# First left-handed primate on the Moon? First in space?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, history, spaceflight-firsts

The various world space agencies' crewed missions have had a long series of firsts, Yuri Gagarin's first being the grandparent of them all.

Crewed space missions are recognized worldwide as barrier-breakers or at least symbols thereof.

Without regard to any other specifier beyond handedness, I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Who was the first left-handed primate on the Moon? Who was the first in space?

Related: [Are there examples of spaceflight equipment being redesigned to remove right hand bias? (To make it less difficult to use left-handed)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55435/12102)

Comment: Regarding the [first primate in space](https://history.nasa.gov/animals.html), that honor might go to a monkey. The first (rhesus) monkey into space was Albert I, in 1948, launched via a V-2. Two Philippines monkeys were launched in 1952 & a squirrel monkey in 1958 & Ham the chimp in 1961. The [handedness of chimps](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835370/) is still being debated.

Comment: Pretty sure there have not yet been any non-human primates on the Moon...

Answer (score 15):

You might want to look at [How many astronauts are left handed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/how-many-astronauts-are-left-handed)

Buzz Aldrin, the second man on the Moon, is left handed.

I think the first lefty in space was Walter Schirra (#9 to space)

In the Apollo era, 1 in 4 astronauts were left-handed. This is much higher than the average left-handedness which is about 1 in 11

Comment: That's an interesting statistic. Although there were so few Apollo-era astronauts that it might not be meaningful. If it persisted through the shuttle era and also with cosmonauts it might be interesting to look for a causal relationship.

Comment: *Great answer!* fyi I've just added a bounty to [How exactly does a magnetoplasmadynamic (MPD) thruster generate thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55416/12102), that Scientific American article looked extremely helpful and a great basis for an answer!

Comment: @Barmar, it's statistically meaningful at the 95% confidence level.  Out of a group of 36 Mercury/Gemini/Apollo astronauts, finding nine left-handers is well above the expected range.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Statistics has never been my strong suit.